# How to create sequence index plots of a subset of groups in a sequence object?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, data-visualization, traminer

I have a state sequence object with a grouping variable that has 6 levels.  I would like to create 3 sequence index plots, one for levels 1 and 2, one for levels 3 and 4, and one for levels 5 and 6, and a legend as a separate plot.  These will be exported to create 3 slides in a presentation.

The group= option in seqIplot does not subset the data.  I tried to subset the data frame to create 3 state sequence objects but not all levels have the same alphabet so that is not a viable solution.  What is an easy way to plot a subset of groups?

Comment: take a look at the `melt` function in the `reshape2` package

Comment: You should name the packages and functions you are using.

Comment: This the function seqIplot in package TraMineR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subset by indexing the state sequence object **and** the grouping variable. If you have a state sequence object called "myseq", a subset vector called "subset" and the data frame where your group variable is stored called "my.data.frame":

```
 seqIplot(myseq[subset, ], group=my.data.frame$mygroup[subset])
```

For instance, you can build the subset vector using

```
 subset <- my.data.frame$mygroup %in% levels(my.data.frame$mygroup)[1:2]
```

OR

```
 subset <- my.data.frame$mygroup %in% c("value1", "value2")
```

Hope this helps

Comment: @user13744 If this helps, why did you not vote for the answer?